# Properties of String reversal and induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have to show that for all $u,v\in A^*$, $(uv)^r = v^r u^r$

I have looked at some youtube videos on how to do mathematical induction since i have not had maths prior to my current course.

From what I understand I have to

- Assume the first thing is true (so, $u$ is true)
- IH: Assume something is true for $n≤k$
- Conclusion: It is true for every $n$

I have no idea how to do this. Do I have to follow the basic form of the IH? It's more understandable with natural numbers, because then I can change the numbers in the formulation to another one, but I have no idea how to do this with a letter.

Answer (score 1):

First show it holds for len u = 1.
Assume it holds for len u = n.
Using that, show for a in A, (auv)$^r$ = v$^r$(au)$^r$.

Surely you can find better help material than youtubed.